# Deny user mysql inject

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

If user input is inserted into an SQL query directly, the application becomes vulnerable to SQL injection, like in the following example:

```
$unsafe_variable = $_POST['user_input'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('" . $unsafe_variable . "')");
```

That's because the user can input something like `value'); DROP TABLE table;--`, making the query:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES('value'); DROP TABLE table;--')
```

What should one do to prevent this?

Comment: Prepared statements are your friend.  But you can't use them if you use mysql_*, and besides, mysql_* is effectively deprecated and you shouldn't use it anyway.  Switch to mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']);`

or i would suggest using `PDO` library instead